# Nunit method and class attribute declaration difference of [Test] and [Test()]

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, automation, nunit

Hi i am doing automation with nunit.
i got doubt.

```
[TestFixture()]
    public class LoginTest
    {
        [Test()]
        public void setup() 
        {
            //setup code
        }
}
```

and

```
[TestFixture]
public class LoginTest
{
    [Test]
    public void setup() 
    {
        //setup code
    }
}
```

What is the difference between giving `[TextFixture]` and `[TextFixture()]`.

Both seems working.
So which is the correct approach?

Comment: There is no difference. Because the Attribute is a class you can instantiate it with the parenthesis. But they're not needed because it is inferred

Comment: They would be needed if you supplied the attribute with some parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can omit them, there is no difference.
In fact you have 4 ways of writing exactly the same attribute:

```
[TestFixture]
[TestFixture()]
[TestFixtureAttribute]
[TestFixtureAttribute()]
```